# Why is my hyperlinked text in another line?

Tags: shiny, hyperlink, whitespace

```
output$abstractText <- renderUI({
tags$div(
   HTML(
      paste("",
            "<span style='font-size: 30px; "Text",
            "",  
            "This tool has been developed by the ",
            tags$a(href = "https://www.","hyperlinked text"),
            ". For news and updates, follow us on Twitter ", 
            tags$a(href = "https://twitter.com", "@xyz"),
            "",
```

From "This tool..." on it appears in 4 lines - how can I have it in one line only?

Comment: Welcome to SO! After reformatting your code, you see that there are some parts missing and the example is not really reproducible. [Please read and follow the recommendations of how to make an example reproducible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Furthermore, after the reformatting you see that the span is also flawed (no closing `'`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say without your full code, but the following example illustrates how you can do that.

You most likely won't need `paste` and no need to mark the elements with `HTML` as `htmltools` will properly render the content. Furthermore, you barely need to create HTML tags by strings (`"<span href=..."`) but you can (and should) simply use the wrappers from library `htmltools` (which is automatically loaded when loading `shiny`).

Having said that, the following snippet shows that all the text is properly in one line:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("link"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$link <- renderUI({
      div(
         span(
            style = "font-size: 30px",
            "Text",
            tags$a(
               href = "https://www.google.com",
               "Hyperlink Text"
            ),
            "For news and updates, follow us on ",
            tags$a(
               href = "https://twitter.com", 
               "Twitter"
            ) 
         )
      )
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Screenshot of the rendered shiny output showing that the content is in one line as intended by the OP]